# Using Spring or using separate project integrated by Spring?

Tags: spring, querydsl

Recently I am trying to use QueryDSL and AMDQ offered by Spring. However, I found Spring just integrates them into itself and some integration like AMDQ stuff is not completed yet. I am new to Spring, but I was wondering what's benefit in using Spring? In my opinion, Spring doesn't make me easier than using these project separately.

Comment: Could you eloborate on where Spring doesn't make it easier?

Comment: My understanding is unless I want to write program having uniform style such as Spring style, Spring doesn't make me easier. Because first I need to know how the things I want to use work(e.g. Hibernate, AspectJ, maybe QueryDSL), then I need to know how Spring integrates them and if there are any limits like version compatibility or any features Spring hasn't not integrated

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Querydsl it offers a nice Data abstraction layer called [Spring Data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data) which supports Querydsl for querying.

Other than that Spring offers also excellent dependency injection functionality and AOP. Unless you want to want to use something else for wiring like EJB or Guice, Spring is a very good choice as an integration layer.

Comment: My understanding is unless I want to write program having uniform style such as Spring style, Spring doesn't make me easier. Because first I need to know how the things I want to use work(e.g. Hibernate, AspectJ, maybe QueryDSL), then I need to know how Spring integrates them and if there are any limits like version compatibility or any features Spring hasn't not integrated.

Comment: What do you mean with Spring style? In case you mean Inversion of Control style, there are not many good alternatives for Java.